# CSS/HTML element formatting template

Tags: html, css, templates

I'm trying to locate an HTML template that shows all the elements in HTML, so that the basic aspects of typography, colour schemes, margins and so on can be applied to it using CSS. Those styles can then be merged with styles that handle the layout for a given project, and then tweaked a little for any given problem.

I realize I could do this myself but thought that someone else may have already done this or know where to find such a template.

Thanks for your help.

*Thanks to David Dorward for clarifying my question*

Comment: What are you even asking exactly?

Comment: Where to find one, I have looked around for awhile now but cant seem to find such an item

Comment: Maybe you can do 1 yourself, with all the divs having different background colors, so that you wont have to ask for a template next time.. I believe for an average programmer, a html page with basic 3-4 divs with different set of widths, heights and colors can be done in a matter of 5-10 minutes, Try it yourself =)

Comment: @robobooga — see the last sentence of the question, and why would it have more than one div in it in the first place anyway? (re edit:) different set widths, heights and colors?! I think you have completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: @David I assumed that "this way I can look at the full style of the elements " supposed to mean that he wants to have a full div filled template of a website and he only needs to change the css styles to see the differences? Or at least that's what i assumed

Comment: @sarnold I dont mean a template that I can style then use on everything I do, I mean a template as mentioned above then every different project I do, I can then style the template and save it as a guide to the project.

Comment: @David Perhaps I haven't worded my question quite right. Its not a template that I can use in all projects its a template to use for all my styles

Comment: I'm assuming that this is about getting a template that shows all the elements in HTML, so that the basic aspects of typography, colour schemes, margins and so on can be applied to it. Those styles can then be merged with styles that handle the layout for a given project, and then tweaked a little for any given problem.

Comment: @Elgoog I suggest you rephrase your question so that everyone here does not have to assume your question

Comment: @Elgoog — feel free to edit a variation of my previous comment into your original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your answer lies here: http://www.tlswebsolutions.com/tag/html-basic-elements/

Comment: David!!! you are a lifesaver. This is exactly what I needed for my css class. I'm just going to use  this and have my students hack on it and do various exercises. I'm so happy about this question, though I think it belongs in the webmasters stack exchange. thank you thank you thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/). It has almost every HTML element, and they have all been styled to the varying tastes of different developers.

Comment: +1: I don't think that forms are included on Zen but I agree it's probably a very good start because having elements only doesn't show their relation that usually happens (like headings and paragraphs for instance) and is important with element margins and/or padding etc. Adding forms can be done later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

One great and well maintained resource for this purpose is the test–file from the normalize.css project, which can be found on [github](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/test.html).